# Excel Importing Getting Error

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, maatwebsite-excel

I want to import my excel (XLSX) file into my database.in my file have 3 sheet and per sheet have 42000 to 55000 row and 11 column.

I am using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

when am going to upload my file that time getting error

```
Serialization of closure failed: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

My code is

```
        Excel::filter('chunk')->load($file)->chunk(250, function($reader) use ($request)
        {
            $filePath = $request->file_name;

            $getFileInfo = session()->get('fileinfo');

            $insertFileInfo = FileInfo::firstOrCreate($getFileInfo);
            $getCaseID = $insertFileInfo->case_id;

            //dd($insertFileInfo);

            $datetime = $request->datetime;

            $aparty = $request->aparty;
            $bparty = $request->bparty;
            $call_duration = $request->call_duration;
            $usage_type = $request->usage_type;
            $lac = $request->lac;
            $cell = $request->cell;
            $imei = $request->imei;
            $imsi = $request->imsi;
            $address = $request->address;
            $network_type = $request->network_type;
            foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {
                foreach ($row as $item) {
                    if (!empty($item[$datetime]) && ($item[$datetime] != $datetime)) {

                        $data = [
                            'case_id' => $getCaseID,
                            'datetime' => $datetime == "NO Data Field" ? '' : Carbon::parse(self::clean($item[$datetime]))->toDateTimeString(),
                            'aparty' => $aparty == "NO Data Field" ? '' : self::clean($item[$aparty]),
                            'bparty' => $bparty == "NO Data Field" ? '' : self::clean($item[$bparty]),
                            'call_duration' => $call_duration == "NO Data Field" ? '0' : str_replace('second(s)', '', $item[$call_duration]) == '' ? '0' : str_replace('second(s)', '', $item[$call_duration]),
                            'usage_type' => $usage_type == "NO Data Field" ? 'Undefined' : str_replace(' ', '_', $item[$usage_type]),
                            'lac' => $lac == "NO Data Field" ? self::convertCellToLac($item[$cell]) : $item[$lac],
                            'cell' => $cell == "NO Data Field" ? self::convertCellFormat($item[$cell]) : self::convertCellFormat($item[$cell]),
                            'imei' => $imei == "NO Data Field" ? 'Undefined' : $item[$imei] == '' ? 'Undefined' : $item[$imei],
                            'imsi' => $imsi == "NO Data Field" ? 'Undefined' : $item[$imsi] == '' ? 'Undefined' : $item[$imsi],
                            'address' => $address == "NO Data Field" ? 'Undefined' : $item[$address] == '' ? 'Undefined' : $item[$address],
                            'network_type' => empty($item[$network_type]) ? 'Undefined' : $network_type == "NO Data Field" ? 'Undefined' : $item[$network_type]
                        ];
                        try {
                            CallCdr::firstOrCreate($data);

                        } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        }

                    }

                }


            }
    });

return redirect()->route('home');
```

of I am not use `use ($request)` then this error gone but I need all request parameter .

Also  not redirect .

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior. You cannot serialize a request.

To solve this you can just assigned the relevant details from the request to separate variable and passed them into `chunk()` instead.

```
$inputs = $request->all(); // returns an array

Excel::filter('chunk')->load($file)->chunk(250, function($reader) use ($inputs) {
   ....
}
```